# In the Misty Grove, I found the dinner table, but none of the commoners is Sanguine / Sam

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Skyrim -- I have all the DLCs and updates.

I had a task that said to go to Morvunskar, despite the fact that I've never been to Rorikstead. I randomly went to Morvunskar and got to the portal to Misty Grove, walked up to about 8 dudes who all looked alike. There was a mission marker I was following that led up to a spot in the grass in front of the table. Nothing.

I talked to all 8 dudes, none of them turned out to be Sanguine -- so I was stuck with no way out.

Had to revert to a previous save and get back. After attempting Misty Grove this way a couple of times, I found that I was supposed to go to Rorikstead to ask about Sam and the staff. But when I got there for the first time, the farmer lady already had her goat. (I may have already killed Grok the Giant, randomly)

Before any of that I managed to speak Ysolda in Whiterun and she went off about a ring and I had no idea what she was talking about and ignored it, until now.

So I'm missing three tasks for the "A Night to Remember" mission, Search Morvunskar for Sam and the Staff. Find Sam. Find the Staff.

The goat was never sold apparently, Ysolda is waiting for a ring and Sanguine won't chat with me to warp me out of Misty Grove.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I guess Sam/Sanguine just decided not to show up.

I fixed it with the moveto command and Sam's refid.

Comment: I take it you had the particular mission involving Sanguine?

Comment: I did initially speak to Sam in the bar, but it looks like I did so many things out of order that Sanguine never showed up in the Misty Grove. I had to use the `moveto player` command to find him and everything worked out ok. I didn't even see the Hagraven.